# Communicating with air-conditioner controller using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to the first time to send and receive information through serial port. The manual for the device with which I am trying to talk can be found [here](http://www.gossenmetrawatt.com/resources/re/r2900/sb_gb.pdf). I am trying for a start to send a set of hexadecimals to ask about the condition of the system and my purpose is to ask in real time about the temperature and store it. Until now my code is this:

```html
import serial
import time

#import serial.tools.list_ports
#ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
#for p in ports:
#    print p

ser = serial.Serial(port= '/dev/ttyUSB0',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0, xonxoff=1, rtscts=1, dsrdtr=1)    

command = "\x10\xFF\x29\x2C\x16"
command = command.decode("hex")
ser.write(command)
print command
#time.sleep(10)
ReceivedData = "\n nothing"
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    ReceivedData = ser.read()
print ReceivedData
```

The problem is that I cannot get any response.

**EDIT:**
So I solved the communication problem. It turned out I was using an extension cable so the T and R channels were not correctly connected. Now The response that I receive is "\x00\x10\xFF\x29\x2C\x16" which is the same that I put in only with a \x00 in the front. Does this mean it is an error message? How do I calculate the 4th bit? Until now I am using an example from the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `command = command.decode("hex")`

just

```
command = "\x10\xFF\x29\x2C\x16"
ser.write(command)
```

should work i am sure it expects bytes like this

to put it differently

```
START_BYTE = "\x10"
ADDR_BYTE = "\xff"
FN_BYTE = "\x29"
CS_BYTE = "\x2C" # We assume you have calculated this right
END_BYTE = "\x16"

msg = START_BYTE+ADDR_BYTE+FN_BYTE+CS_BYTE+END_BYTE
ser.write(msg)
```

you can abstract this out since start and end and address are always the same

```
def send_fn(ser,FN_CMD):
    START_BYTE = "\x10"
    ADDR_BYTE = "\xff"   
    END_BYTE = "\x16"
    CS_BYTE = chr((ord(ADDR_BYTE) + ord(FN_CMD))&0xFF)
    msg = START_BYTE+ADDR_BYTE+FN_CMD+CS_BYTE+END_BYTE
    ser.write(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried without .decode but it still doesn't work. My thought is that the port is not opened properly. For example when I test with getCTS() getDSR() and getCD() I get False in everything. Maybe this means that the pins are not configured properly. I cannot see how to implement the scheme from page 4 of the instructions.

Comment: I cannot understand the expression CS_BYTE = chr((ord(ADDR_BYTE) + ord(FN_CMD))&0xFF). I understand the the CS_BYTE should be the sum of ADDR_BYTE and the FN_CMD in hex but what this expression gives me is not that.

Comment: it should be ... the and 0xFF just ensures it is only one byte ... and then `chr` converts it from an int back into a byte that is ready to be transmitted

Comment: Ok it works! Thanks a lot! If it is not much of a trouble could you please explain how this &0xFF operation ensures that I send one byte? Or put a reference so I can understand it? Thank you again.

Comment: its just a binary and ... 0xff is the maximum value allowed for a single byte ...

Comment: consider for example `0xfe + 0xf3`, which is 493 which is the same as 0x1ed, which requires 2 bytes to encode so if we take it as binary `111110001` and we `and` it with 0xff (`11111111` in binary) that truncates the 1 farthest to the left and we get `11110001` which is 241( or 0xf1 in hex) which can be encoded in a single byte of `"\xf1"`